# Setting position Axist on gameobject in code moves it to wrong coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cloud in my game that moves from right to left. Until it has hit a collider - this collider is JUST supposed to bring that cloud all the way back to its beginning. So the cloud cycles over and over through the scene.

I have two questions:

1. The optimal way for me would be to give the cloud a "spawning zone" where it just spawns after hitting the resetting collider. However, I didn't find any information about spawning zones.
2. So, I decided just to alter the position values in code once the collider triggers. Well the cloud gets set to a different space BUT not to the coordinates I gave to it.

In both examples, it is important only to change the X position of the cloud. The height (Y) and depth (Z) should remain the same.

This is what I achieved and works not quite as expected:

```c#
public class CloudScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Reset Clouds Collider") // detect collision with ground game object 
        {
            float tempY = transform.position.y;
            float tempZ = transform.position.z;
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(5, tempY, tempZ);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

In this script, I would expect the cloud to maintain its Y AND Z position and just alter the X to 5. However, the cloud stars at Y = 5, and after the translator goes to Y =4. After another cycle Y = 3.... Also Z gets set to 0, while it started at 1....

Comment: do you maybe want to use `localPosition` instead?

Comment: Yeah did that before. However this still set the cloud to not quite where I wanted it to be ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `localPosition` you also have to get the temp values from `localPosition`

```c#
float tempY = transform.localPosition.y;
float tempZ = transform.localPosition.z;
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(5, tempY, tempZ);
```

---

In order to reset to the initial position you could also simply store it e.g. at `Start` (depending on your needs it could also be `OnEnable` or via a public method) like

```c#
private Vector3 initPosition;

private void Start()
{
    // store original position
    initPosition = transform.localPosition;
}
```

and than simply reset to that one instead

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    // detect collision with ground game object
    if (collider.gameObject.name == "Reset Clouds Collider")  
    {
        // restore original position
        transform.localPosition = initPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah geez. that was really dumb of me. Anyway - would you be so awesome to tell me how, instead of using a 5 in code, set the 5 to a spawning point? that would be a bit more dynamic :)

Comment: updated my answer ;) Now you can still decide whether to use `localPosition` or `position` for both lines (depending on how the parent object is moved etc)

Comment: Glad to help ;)